# How to relaunch a daemon after it crashes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

In Linux,I have a daemon and I want to start it at bootup. If it crashes then I need to relaunch it.

One of the ways I have tried is using /etc/inittab, but the problem I see it gets launched various times and the message displays "respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes".
I guess this is because for making daemon, the parent exits and only child process survives.
The exit of parent is causing it to respawn.

Is there some way I can get what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/). This service will monitor your system and take care of crashed services and much more.

If you're using `systemd`, you can specify, that service should be respawned on abort:

```
Restart=on-abort
```

See this [article](http://patrakov.blogspot.de/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

supervisor

Supervisor is a client/server system that allows its users to monitor and control a number of processes on UNIX-like operating systems.